# How did Freebase verify that information submitted is correct?

Tags: google, wikidata

Freebase, was a service from Google, a "free, open knowledge graph of 39 million people, places, and things.". This service was retired. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebase_(database)), it was succeeded by [Wikidata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikidata)

As far as I can tell, anyone can submit information, manually and/or automatically to Freebase.

How did Freebase ensure that the information it presents to people is reasonably accurate and correct?